# How to Override JMS connectionfactory and queues in a Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, jms, jndi

I am new to Spring Boot and JMS and trying to do a setup with a simple Producer class for sending a message to queue. I want to create a generic class which can work both on ActiveMQ as well as Weblogic.
While testing with ActiveMQ, if i do a lookup with 'ConnectionFactory' and dynamicqueues it works fine.
But when i try to do the lookup from properties file, it is throwing me a 'NameNotFound exception'.

The queue and connection factory already exist on weblogic as well as activemq.

Below is the code ApplicationConfig.java //setup for bean instantiation

```
        @Configuration
        @EnableJMS
        public class AppConfiguration{

        @Autowired
        private JMSProperties jmsProps;

        @Bean
        public InitialContex getInitialContext() throws Exception{
        InitialContext ctx = null;
        try{
        ctx = new InitialContext();}
        catch(NamingException ne){
        throw ne;
        }
        }
        return ctx;
        }

        @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory getconnFac(InitialContext ctx) throws Exception{
        ConnectionFactory cf = null;
        try{
        cf = (ConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup(jmsProps.getConnectionFactoryJndi());
        }
        catch(NamingException ne){
        throw ne;
        }
        return cf;
        }


        @Bean
        public Destination getDest(InitialContext ctx) throws Exception {
        Destination dest = null;
        try{
        dest = (Destination) ctx.loolup (jmsProps.getTargetQueueJndi());
        }
        catch(NamingException ne){
        throw ne;
        }
        return dest;
        }


        @Bean
        public JmsTemplate getJmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory cf){
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(cf);
        return jmsTemplate;
        }
        }
```

JmsProperties.java // file to read the jms properties

```
        @Component
        @ConfigurationProperties
        @PropertySouce("classpath:/jms.properties")
        public class JmsProperties{
        private String targetQueueJndi;
        private String connectionFactoryJndi;

        public String getTargetQueueJndi(){
        return targetQueueJndi;
        }

        public void setTargetQueueJndi(String targetQueueJndi){
        this.targetQueueJndi = targetQueueJndi;
        }

        public String getConnectionFactoryJndi(){
        return connectionFactoryJndi;
        }

        public void setConnectionFactoryJndi(String connectionFactoryJndi){
        this.connectionFactoryJndi = connectionFactoryJndi;
        }

        }
```

jms.properties // file to find the actual connection factory and queue

```
        connection-factory.name = MQOOFDEACF
        connection-factory.local-jndi = jms/MQOOFDEACF

        target-queue.name = MQOOFDEAQ
        target-queue.local-jndi = jms/MQOOFDEAQ


        application-loc.properties

        target-queue-jndi = ${target-queue.local-jndi}
        connection-factory-jndi=${connection-factory.local-jndi}
```

Exception thrown: // exception thrown while building

```
caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instatiate [javax.jms.ConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'getConnFac' threw exception; nested excetion is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jms/MQOOFDEACF
```

Comment: its not the same question. please remove the duplicate